# tlmgr how to disable switch to user mode?

Tags: packages, texlive, installing

Everytime I run `tlmgr` to install packages, I get the following messages:

```
$ sudo tlmgr install xetex
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
tlmgr: package repository http://ftp.gwdg.de/pub/ctan/systems/texlive/tlnet
Package luatex is not relocatable, cannot install it in user mode!
Package pdftex is not relocatable, cannot install it in user mode!
Package xetex is not relocatable, cannot install it in user mode!
```

So no package gets installed and although I already use `sudo`, the `tlmgr` switches back to user mode automatically, which I don't even want (afaik).

How do I fix this behavior and install packages?

**Additional Information**

```
$ tlmgr --version
tlmgr revision 39298 (2016-01-07 03:44:29 +0100)
tlmgr using installation: /usr/local/texlive/2015
TeX Live (http://tug.org/texlive) version 2015
```

The `tlmgr` was installed using the `install-tl` script from [here](https://github.com/scottkosty/install-tl-ubuntu), using:

```
sudo ./install-tl-ubuntu
```

The output of `which`:

```
$ which tlmgr
/opt/texbin/tlmgr
```

The output of `sudo which`:

```
$ sudo which
/usr/bin/tlmgr
```

Comment: Was this installed via apt-get? I think that was the cost Debian made the users pay to allow for tlmgr in their packages. I typically install the TUG texlive (advisable to install it as a special user, not root, and then maintain it as that user)

Comment: @daleif Added information to my question answering your questions.

Comment: Pass, (1)  never used that script, prefers to know what is being done, (2) no idea why your system behaves like this. (3) that tlmgr placement is a little strange, but I'm guessing texbin is a symlink. Is the tlmgr path the same for the sudo?

Comment: Try `sudo /opt/texbin/tlmgr install xetex`...

Comment: @Zelphir Rather thank norbert who has found the cause of your problem in its answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two installations of TeX Live. One from the distribution (in /usr) and one installed from the TUG installer (in /opt). The problem is that when you use sudo the path is reset and the tlmgr in/usr/bin is used, and thus does not work on the TUG installation.

You need to adjust the PATH variable also for the root user, or - better in my opinion - if it is a single user system, change the ownership of the files in/opt/texlive to your user ID, then you can use tlmgr without sudo.

Comment: To call the correct `tlmgr`, you can specify the method I suggested in my comment.